# Laravel Test doesn't execute tearDown method when fails

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Im implementing a HTTP test in Laravel, but I observed that whenever my test fails, the `tearDown` method doesn't get called. How can I achieve to call it even the test fails, programmatically? I just want to clean up things in each test.

**UPDATE**

The method that I've mentioned is a Laravel's built-in. I'll explain two lifecycles of a test in Laravel, first is the `setUp`, which is a method that you may override to include some initializations you might need in each test. The second one is the `tearDown`, which is used to clean up any "residue" from the test. So my Base Test class looks like this...

```
public function setUp() {
  ...some initializations
}

public function tearDown() {
  $this->someModelInstance->delete();
}
```

All are working fine but whenever a test fails, only the setUp has been called. All the "residue" remains in the database. What I want is to "clean up" the "residue" even a test fails.

Comment: Show the code, we cant help you without it

Comment: You should not rely on teardown to clean up your tests, if testcase errors unexpectedly you cant expect data to be clean. You should rely on setup to secure your data is correct, Laravel already has systems for this, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: Im using multiple databases that's why I need to cleanup the other databases as well using the `tearDown()`.

Comment: but the point you should not do it on tearDown but setup should secure your environment is fresh

Comment: I'm starting to get your point, I'll try your suggestions first, I'll get back to you. Thanks!